# Conditionally apply Paragraph Style to text in a Table

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have this code that works:

```js
var myTable = app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().getElements();  

for(i=0; i<myTable.length; i++) {  
  myTable[i].cells[0].insertionPoints[0].appliedParagraphStyle = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyleGroups.item("Wycena").paragraphStyles.item("Nazwa A. Numeracja2"); 
}
```

This code applies one *Paragraph Style* to all rows in a Table, however what I need is as follows:

- If I paste text that *does* begin with a bullet symbol (`•`) into a Table then apply *"Paragraph Style 1"*
- If I paste text that *does not* begin with a bullet symbol (`•`) into a Table then apply *"Paragraph Style 2"*.

What I think I need is an `if` statement somewhere, but I cant work it out.

Comment: if this is the same question as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764799/adobe-changing-table-style-script), then I suggest you delete your previous question by clicking the _"Delete"_ button below it. In the future, If you want to make changes to a question you should click the `"Edit"` button and make changes to your original question instead of asking the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Paragraph Style 2 to all the text and then run the script to format only the text with the bullet symbol:

```
var myDocument = app.documents.item(0);    
var allCells = myDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().cells.everyItem().getElements();  
for ( var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++)  
{  

if ( allCells[i].contents.indexOf('•') > -1)  
{  
    allCells[i].appliedCellStyle = 'Paragraph Style 1';  
    allCells[i].clearCellStyleOverrides();  
 }  
}
```

You can change the "•" to any other text you want a specific format and that cell will be formatted accordingly.